# Where is the OpenShift Web SSL Configuration Area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, openshift, redhat

I upgraded to RedHat's OpenShift Online Bronze level to host a Ruby on Rails application.

From this [blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/domain-names-and-ssl-in-the-openshift-web-console/) which is a little over a year old I see that:

> The web console now allows you to configure your application’s hostname, and set up secure access to custom domains through a new SSL certificate configuration area.

But I can't find it anywhere. Near the bottom of that post they show what it looks like when they talk about the warning you would see if you don't upgrade to bronze or silver. It looks like I would be able to upload my certificate and key files if I could find it.

I don't see anything under the Applications or Settings tabs. Has it been removed?

I found the command line to use to add the certificate and key:

```
rhc alias update-cert App_Name Domain_Name --certificate Cert_File --private-key Key_File
```

But that does not provide the option to add the intermediate certificates or certificate chain. Maybe those are completely unnecessary? I don't know.

Does anyone else have more information on this? I've been doing searches for this for a while and that is all I could come up with.

Comment: I ended up using the command line and not worrying about the intermediate certificates and it worked. I'm still curious about the web interface for SSL and whether I lose anything by not including the intermediate certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the web ssl area:

1.)  Log into the OpenShift web console at www.openshift.com
2.)  click on the application that you want to install an ssl certificate for
3.)  click on the "change" link next to the application name near the top of the page, this could also be "change alias" if you have previously assigned the applicatoin an alias such as "www.example.com"
4.)  click "edit" next to the alias that you have already added
You should now see the form fields to add an ssl certificate.

Comment: Thanks! I know I clicked on "change alias" but I don't remember seeing the "edit" link or maybe it just wasn't obvious to me that editing the alias included adding the SSL certificate. It makes sense now.